# ruby on rails bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am new with ruby on rails I have successfully  installed ruby on rails 4.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 and created new app but when i started server to see if it is working by writing

```
rails server
```

I get this error message

```
Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 5.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

and when i start to install bundle 
i get other packages that need to be installed before bundle

and when i start to install bundle 
i get other packages that need to be installed before bundle

error message

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for "rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net" port 443 (https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest-5.5.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing minitest (5.5.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install minitest -v '5.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

after i installed minitest and run bundle install

i got this error message

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for "rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net" port 443 (https://rubygems.org/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

and continue like that showing me packages that i need to install before bundle

Comment: Could you provide the error after you "budle install"?

Comment: "and when i start to install bundle i get other packages that need to be installed before bundle and are many files" - Can you explain this further? What exactly happens when you bundle install?

Answer (score 1):

It says your bundle is not installed. Please try `bundle install` from your project root directory.

Comment: i got this error message 

    Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for "rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net" port 443 (https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest-5.5.1.gem)
    An error occurred while installing minitest (5.5.1), and Bundler cannot
    continue.
    Make sure that `gem install minitest -v '5.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.